# How to start mongodb with python?

Tags: python, mongodb, bash

I'm trying to run a shell file on python:

```
mongod --config /opt/mongodb/mongod.conf
```

and call it on python:

```
subprocess.call(['bash', 'run.sh'])
```

but it says `mongod : not found`.

When I run it in the terminal it works.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `bash`. Just run it as a normal script as you do in terminal:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['./run.sh'])
```

Also it seems that `mongod` is not in your system environment path so you need to add absolute path of `mongod` to your `run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1404-3.0.6/bin/mongod --config /opt/mongodb/mongod.conf
```

Comment: OS [ERRno 2] no such file file or directory

Comment: @Are you running the python script in the same directory of `run.sh`? Try to use `subprocess.call(['sh', '<abs path to your run.sh>'])`.

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe `mongod` is not in your python env. Try to edit your `run.sh` and use the absolute path of `mongod` you can find it with `whereis mongod`.

Comment: Thanks i edit run.sh to /opt/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1404-3.0.6/bin/mongod --config /opt/mongodb/mongod.conf and it work

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
import os
os.system('bash run.sh')
```

update command to :

```
 #!/bin/sh
 /usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /opt/mongodb/mongod.conf
```

Comment: i already update to                                                                                         /opt/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1404-3.0.6/bin/mongod --config /opt/mongodb/mongod.conf                                                                            
 and it work . Thanks .